# Плагин для нажатия кнопок на экране и написания текста

Tags: c#, плагин

Мне нужен плагин, позволяющий моей программе делать нажатия на экране(левая, правая кнопки мыши) мог писать в заданной строчке текст ну и такое подобное.

Comment: Плагин называется WinApi, пользуйтесь на здоровье

Comment: По сути только через pinvoke, смотреть в Гугле. Более оптимально писать на вин апи на `C/C++` и потом вызывать это из кода `C#`